# Possible to modify jQuery id selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Probably this can't be done, but in case I'm missing something:

Is it possible to temporarily modify the jQuery id selector("#") so as to operate on say...a DocumentFragment, or an element removed from the DOM instead of the default behavior?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm trying to optimize some legacy code that heavy utilizes id selectors in order to perform some heavy-lifting DOM manipulation. However, all those ids are under a single element. I read that if that element was removed from the dom, manipulated, and then inserted back performance would be much better. Which can't be done because of all those "#" selectors...

(Sidenote: performance was noticeably improved by setting display:none before the manipulation, but still slow).

Comment: No... only elements present in the document can be found by `getElementById`. You can always use other traversal methods though.

Comment: Selectors can only select from the DOM. What you want to do is store those fragments as JavaScript variables.

Comment: You could limit the searches of your selectors by passing the single ancestor element as the context.

Comment: @jbabey The performance penalty isn't because of the searches, it's because of the manipulation on the results. (eg on the found element, create 10000 child elements,etc)

Comment: @pkExec the key in the case of those manipulations is to create all the elements first, then push them to the DOM as one large update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors can only select from the DOM. What you want to do is store those fragments as JavaScript variables.

```
$p = $('p').remove();
// ...
$('body').append(someFunction($p));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/tjVUM/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if you store a reference to the removed element in a variable:

```
// Get a div by id
var div = $('#thediv'); 
// Remove it from the DOM
div.remove();
// Change the color of the text inside it to red
// Notice we're selecting with the div as the context
$('p', div).css('color', 'red');
// Re-add div to DOM; text will be red
document.body.appendChild(div[0]);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sglIk